# Making PHP applications available as subdirectories in an ASP.NET site

Tags: php, iis, asp.net

As an example, say my domain is example.com, that's an ASP.NET site on IIS 7.5.  I'd like to get phpBB installed and available at example.com/forum.

If I set up phpBB as it's own application, outside of example.com, I can get it going just fine on the same IIS server as the ASP.NET app, but when I try to install it as an app inside the example.com site, or as a virtual directory inside example.com, the installer hangs when trying to connect to the MySQL database. I get an HTTP 500 error from IIS:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\php\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout
```

This error occurs with both of the PHP apps I'm trying to install.  In both instances, it's when the app attempts to connect to the database.

I'm entirely unsure how to fix this, or even if it's fixable.  Plain vanilla PHP pages work fine (eg. `<? print phpinfo(); ?>` does what it's supposed to).  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

From your description of the problem, I'm assuming PHP is already installed and working on your server if running PHP scripts on another web site than example.com.

Ok, two questions here:

- First of all, which version of IIS?
- Second one: can you get a simple PHP page to run in your example.com website, or does this result in the same error, too?

---

### Update:

This doesn't seem related to PHP at all, but specifically to PHPBB; I also suggest checking the documentation for running in virtual directories, and also trying to set it up in a VD of another web site, to completely rule out anything related to example.com.

Comment: +1 on testing out a simple php page like, `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>`.  It may be that phpBB requires you to specify the appropriate webroot somewhere in the configuration; this is common with alot of LAMP Web applications.

Comment: IIS 7.5.  <?php echo phpinfo(); ?> works as expected.  Updated the question to reflect these points.

Comment: I used phpBB as an example because it's what I assumed most people would be familiar with, but the same behavior occurs with another php app I'm trying to install.  It both instances, the installer hangs when attempting to contact the MySQL database.

Comment: Could be an issue with application pools and their identities and/or settings. Are all of your web sites running in the same AP, or do they use different ones?

Comment: Checking...  OK - I have two relevant application pools:  the main ASP.NET app pool, and a pool for phpApp1.  phpApp1 is running as a application under the main asp.net site, but it's using it's own application pool.  phpApp2 is currently running as a virtual directory of the asp.net application.  The problem occurs in both situations.

Comment: Ok, and when it does **not** occur (as in another website), which application pool is used?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at phpBB's documentation for running in a sub-directory? You may be required to make a change to a constant (usually in a config file) to reflect the webroot.  This is the case for 90% of the open source LAMP apps I've setup before.

Comment: I don't believe that's the problem.  I've edited the question above to say this, but it happens with another PHP app, at the same point in its install process: when trying to connect to the database.

Comment: What are you putting in for the MySQL "host" field?  i.e. is the MySQL database on the same box?  If so, you should be putting in `localhost`.

Comment: Yep, the DB is on the same box, and it's _trying_ to connect to 'localhost'.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that phpBB requires you to specify the appropriate webroot somewhere in the configuration; this is common with alot of LAMP Web applications.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Thanks for your answer. Please note that the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq#signatures) requests that you not use a signature.